# How do I use logback DBAppender in JBoss AS 7?

Tags: logging, jboss7.x

We want to log to a database, and we're using SLF4J as API. Logback is the "natural" implementation, and it contains a `DBAppender`, which we'd like to use.

However, from what I've read a direct configuration is impossible in JBoss (we use EAP 6, which is based on AS 7).

I've already seen a JBoss module with a SysLog appender that simply delegates to logback and contains logback configuration. I've also seen another JBoss module custom log handler that logs to a database.

However, my goal is to kind of integrate both and log to a given DB with the least possible hassle. It seems that I will be forced to write a custom log handler, but I just want it to delegate to Logback and its `DBAppender`. Also I want to use a `JNDIConnectionSource` from the Datasources that we've deployed on JBoss anway. Finally, I'd like to configure the logback configuration with values that I set in the JBoss configuration within the `custom-handler` using the `properties`.

Do you think it's possible? And how can it be done? Would this be of general interest?

Comment: Just an FYI in EAP 6.1 there is a SyslogHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss AS 7, JBoss EAP and WildFly all use the JBoss Log Manager which is an extension of `java.util.logging.LogManager` to configure logging. You could probably wrap a `DBAppender` in some kind of `java.util.logging.Handler` (or `org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler`). That is how log4j appenders are handled when they are defined as `custom-handler`'s.

That said it probably wouldn't be all the difficult to just write one. You should be able to lookup a datasource and just use raw SQL to insert the data. I'm pretty sure that's all the logback appender is doing.